# Landsat 7 Collection 2 Gap Filling

Tags: landsat-7, filling, gap

I am trying to apply gap filling to Landsat 7, Tier 1 Collection 2 images.

The outcome images are still perforated.

What is missing?

````
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/vaibhavpuri/NCR");
/***** End of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. *****/
var startYear = 2000;
var endYear = 2001;

var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear, 1, 1);
var endDate = startDate.advance(1,'year');
// print(startDate, endDate)

// Cloud Mask

var cloudMaskL7 = function(image) {
  var dilatedCloud = (1 << 1)
  var cloud = (1 << 3)
  var cloudShadow = (1 << 4)
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(dilatedCloud)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud))
    .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadow))
  // var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(dilatedCloud).eq(0).and(
  //   qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud).eq(0)).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadow).eq(0))
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(mask.not()).updateMask(mask2);
}

var l7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")
  .map(cloudMaskL7);
  
// ##### SLC gap filling function for cloud masked L7 collection #######
// // ================================================================================
var kernelSize = 25;// Tried with 5, 10, 20, 30
var kernel = ee.Kernel.square(kernelSize * 30, 'meters', false);

var GapFill = function(image) {
  var start = image.date().advance(-1, 'year');
  var end = image.date().advance(1, 'year');
  var fill = l7.filterDate(start, end).median();
  var regress = fill.addBands(image); 
  var regress1 = regress.select(regress.bandNames().sort());
  var fit = regress1.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.linearFit().forEach(image.bandNames()), kernel, null, false);
  var offset = fit.select('.*_offset');
  var scale = fit.select('.*_scale');
  var scaled = fill.multiply(scale).add(offset);
  return image.unmask(scaled, true);
};


var l7Masked = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(roi))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
  .map(cloudMaskL7);
print(l7Masked);
  
var l7mg = l7Masked.map(GapFill);
  
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}
var addIndex = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']).rename(['ndvi']);
var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename(['ndwi']); 
var ndbi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B2', 'SR_B4']).rename(['ndbi']); 

  return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi).addBands(ndbi);
};
var filtered = l7mg.map(applyScaleFactors).map(addIndex);
print(filtered);

var view = filtered.median().clip(roi);
var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 0.3,
};

Map.addLayer(view, visualization, 'True Color (321)');
Map.centerObject(roi, 10);```
````